# Create an <object> with <param> using JS/DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In HTML you have something like:

```
<object ...>
 <param name="onLoad" value="loaded"/>
</object>
```

You can achieve this through JS by simply writing the `innerHTML` but I'd rather do it 'properly'. For the `<object>` itself:

```
var object = document.createElement("object");
object.id = ...;
```

But how do I add the params?

Comment: `var param = document.createElement("param"); object.appendChild(param);` would be my guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var obj = document.createElement('object');
obj.appendChild( document.createElement('param') );
document.body.appendChild(obj);
```